# Automatic bump mapping

Tags: texturing, geometry, normal-map

[image]

In the image, I know that setting Normal to a value (other than 0) in geometry will create a bump map from the texture onto the material. It works well and I'm doing this for the hair of a human model. What is the difference between positive and negative? Does one bump in one way and the other the exact opposite? (So if 1.0 bumps it outwards by a certain amount, -1.0 bumps it inwards by the same amount).

But my main question is the Bump Mapping **Method** and **Space**. What do these do exactly? I looked up on [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/influence/material.html) and it doesn't specify their purposes, only shows the available options. **What is the difference between these options?** I found that Original method (which will for some reason disable Space) looks the best to me but I want to make sure that option is the most appropriate for the situation I am in.

Comment: No one figure it out yet?

Comment: I did ORiginal and it broke. I did highest quality and it was the highest quality.

Comment: For space, check out http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Normal_Map_Technical_Details .

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, if normal is positive light colours bump outwards and dark inwards, if negative - the other way round.

The rest doesn't seem easy, but here are some links. I think "Method" is mostly about quality:
http://kishalmi.servus.at/3D/bumpcode/

"Space" should tell in which space the normal vector will be stored. But the results look strange.

Anyway - why not use cycles?

Comment: I know cycles is much better but it seems too complicated and different. And I don't have much time to learn.

Comment: The thing I'm scared about space is I'm afraid it will make the bump map be projected from another object, thus if I move the hair, it's bump will change, which is not realistic.

Comment: Cycles is not too complicated (although it is different). Watch this and see what you think: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-cycles/

Comment: For "Method', select the quality level you need. For realtime, 'Low quality" is much faster than the higher ones. "Compatible" (for me) does not do anything. I think it's a fallback option for old Blender versions.
The "space" dropdown, afaik, is only relevant for normal maps. This is why it's greyed out.
For the "normal" value, you may want to try very small vaues like 0.05.